# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘raster’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):

Tags: r

While i am trying to load library Raster i am getting error as follow:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘raster’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/A132054/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘raster’ was built under R version 4.0.2

It was working fine earlier and other system as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would reinstall `raster` after first reinstalling the packages it uses.

```
install.packages(c("Rcpp", "rgdal", "sp", "terra", "raster"))
```

It would be even better to first install R 4.0.2